# Show that $\frac{1}{x}-\sin(x)$ has exactly one root in the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: limits, functions, roots

I have problems showing, 
that this function has exact one root in the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$:
$$f(x):=\frac{1}{x}-\sin(x)$$

My idea was to use the Intermediate value theorem,  but the problem is that the theorem is only specified for closed intervals $[a,b]$ and that the function must be continuous in that interval -  which both is not the case.
The limits are $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} = -\infty$$ and  $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{2}{\pi}-1$$

I plotted the function with WolframAlpha and it showed that the root must be at around 1.1...(the value is irrelvant in this case).

My next idea was to calculate the derivate to show if the function is monotonic increasing/decreasing, which solves to:
$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-cos(x) <0$$ => monotonically decreasing.
But I still can't say anything about the root.

But I am stuck, I don't know if my idea is right and/or how to continue, especially because the interval is half open.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=+\infty.$$

As you say

$$\lim_{x\to (\pi/2)^-} f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}-1<0.$$

Because of continuity of $f$ there exists $a,b\in (0,\pi/2)$ such that $a<b,$ $f(a)>0$ and $f(b)<0.$ Then, by Bolzano's theorem, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0.$

Now assume there are two solutions of the equation, say $c,d$ with $c<d.$ Then, by Rolle's theorem there exists $e\in (c,d)$ such that $f'(e)=0.$ This contradicts the fact that $f'<0.$ Thus, the initial assumption is not correct. That is, $f$ has no two zeros.

Comment: This was my immediate idea, but the precondition for continuity and Bolzanos theorem is, that I have a closed interval and not an open, that was my problem

Comment: You don't use $(0,\pi/2)$ as the inteval to apply Bolzano's theorem. You have to choose a smaller interval, even if you don't give it explicitely. Note that $\lim_{0^-}>0$ and $\lim_{(\pi/2)^+}<0$ is enough. Moreover, in this case, you can use $\pi/2$ as the right extreme of the interval.

Comment: So, whenever I encounter an open/half open interval, then I try to find an closed interval, use Bolzanos theorem together with Rolle, to show the existence of a root and the uniqueness.

Comment: Yes. In the worst scenario you have an open/open interval. In the function is continuous and the lateral limits have different sign, there exists a closed interval where you can proceed as we have done (and you know how to do it). Maybe, you will find interesting to show that any polynomial of degree $3$ (or odd) have a root. Here there is no interval given. But considering $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}$ would help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Note that, for $x \leq 1$, $\dfrac1x - \sin x > 0$ so you can restrict your attention to $[1,\pi/2]$.

Next, assume that there are two zeros. Now apply the *mean* value theorem (rather than intermediate value theorem).

Comment: Hm, I know the mean value theorem, but I am not understand why this should help me, I mean, I would get sth like this:
$$\frac{f(\frac{\pi}{2})-f(1)} {\frac{\pi}{2}-1} = f'(\xi)$$
But this would only help me find out where f'(x) is zero, but not f in general?

Comment: Suppose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are (distinct) zeros of $f$ (and that $x_1 < x_2$). Apply the mean value theorem on $[x_1,x_2]$.

Comment: I $x_1,x_2$ are zeros of $f$, then Rolles theorem says, that there exists an root of the derivate of f(x). So now I must show that in this case there is only one root of f(x).
Edit//: When I understand it correct from @mfl answer below, due to the monotonically decreasing there could only exist one root of f?

Comment: Exactly: if there are two roots of $f$, then the derivative vanishes somewhere. But you know that the derivative is strictly negative, thus non vanishing, and you have your contradiction.